# platform specific placement of alignment padding in C structures

Tags: c, alignment

Unless packing compiler options or pragmas are used, code like the following (assuming 8-bit char and 16-bit short)

```
struct foo
{
   short a ;
   char  b ;
   short c ;
} ;
```

will end up with, to the best of my knowledge, an alignment pad of 1 byte before `c` on all the platforms that our product supports (quite a few).

I don't recall seeing any platform that didn't put the alignment padding between `b` and `c`, but imagine that a compiler could just as legally put the padding between `a` and `b`.

(Motivation: we are introducing some infrastructure in our code to ensure binary compatibility of some structures that are currently written out to disk or involved in network flows, and where possible, would like to insert explicit padding so that other developers are aware of the additional storage being consumed under the covers by these data structures).

Does anybody know of a platform who's compiler does not put alignment padding, when required, immediately before the member that would be unaligned otherwise?

Comment: Interesting question. I am curious why you asked your question in this manner about this C hazard zone, are you willing to share your motivation?

Comment: What if some platform aligns `short`s and `char`s to 4 bytes? There may be good reasons for that on future platforms, e.g:  http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/DataRaces

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading [Write Portable Code](http://www.hookatooka.com/wpc/).  Using structures to serialize your data isn't a good idea.  Packing and endianess will get you every time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put that book in my reading list.  Note however, that our product (IBM's DB2 server) is massive, and there's a lot of momentum and inertia in a codebase like this.  For the near future, not using structures to serialize the data isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

It's not default anywhere that I'm aware of, but MSVC (and gcc, I believe, for compatbility) supported `#pragma pack` which allows for control over structure packing and permits misaligned accesses.

Basically, any assumption of the byte layout of a C structure is just asking for trouble.  Code that does that tends also to fall into the trap of making assumptions about word endianness, something that **absolutely is** incompatible between common platforms.

Comment: `#pragma pack` is what I meant in my question by 'packing pragmas'.  I'm interested in the default behaviour, when `#pragma pack` or equivalent (evil) compiler options are NOT used.

Comment: And I repeat my warning: if you make assumptions about structure layout, you will expose yourself to terrible portability bugs in the future.  Don't do that.  Cook your storage, don't pickle memory.